# Show gif when page is not loaded?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show a spinner .gif when the page is not loaded. Then, when the page is loaded, the spinner must be hidden. I searched, but found nothing.

Is there an example for this? How can I do this?

Comment: what defines when the page is loaded? the DOM tree is loaded pretty quickly, but images might take longer

Answer (score 0):

add your spinner as a normal img tag and give him an id then on documentReady remove the tag

in your html:

```
<img src="your;gif" id="spinner" />
```

then in javascript code using jquery:

```
$(function(){ $('#spinner').remove(); })
```

Comment: $(document).ready() fires even before all the images have been loaded. So it might be possible that the spinner gif is not yet loaded when you remove it

Comment: yes, good point, but should work properly on second call as the image will probably be cached and propbably on first call if the page take sufficient time to load that it require displaying a spinner